# Find the count of elements in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to develop a C++ program. I am facing a problem. I have declared an array of length 100 as `int arr[100]`.

But I have only filled 20 entries in it. Now I want to find the total number of elements in the array, which should be 20. How do I find the number of elements filled in the array?

I have tried

```
int size= sizeOf(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

but this gives me 100. I only want to get the elements which I have allowed the user to enter.

Actually, there is a situation where the number of generated outputs can be any number. So I assigned each value in a separate array as `arr[]`. Then I want a loop through the length of the array.

How to calculate the total number of outputs I am getting in the array?

Comment: Is this homework? Or can you use an `std::vector`?

Comment: Consider using [std::vector](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html#VECTOR).

Comment: You could increment a counter as you assign values to the array, or if your code allows for it, use std::vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you work with fixed-size arrays for which you want to consider some positions empty and the others filled, you must keep track of the filled element count in a separate variable. Why? Because you *always* have 100 elements in your array - you created them. Only that you are not *using* some of them - and only you know that.

This is one of the many reasons why you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: no, its not an homework.. its just for my practice. I am trying to improve my programming skills and went through this problem. I havent studied anything about vector.. I will try for it also. Thnx..

Comment: @user601236: I never said that this was homework. @birryree did, just above.

Answer (score 1):

With C/C++ arrays, there is no way to determine this unless you have another variable keeping track.

You might actually be looking for a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The features you want can be found in `std::vector`, and `std::deque`.

When using C++, it is preferred to use the standard containers over the C-style arrays.

Comment: No, `std::array` doesn't track "used" separately from "capacity".

Comment: @BenVoigt You are correct.  I've edited to remove the inaccurate portion (though, `std::array` would still be preferred over a C-style array).