# Logical Size (number of elements) in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array (defined below) and I want to find the number of elements in it and send in mehtod call.

So, I have this:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 20;          // Maximum size of data array
double givenDataPoints[MAX_SIZE] = {0, 2, 3.8, 5, 9, 16, 16.2, 17, 18, 19, 19.5};
```

And i want to get

```
int logicalSize = //this should be 10 because I only put in 10 numbers, not 20
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Just a suggestion but you should consider using  `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of naked arrays.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious this is part of a hw assignment and I'm not sure I'm allowed to do that so I'd like to explore other options first.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of doing that, you'll have to track it manually.

Comment: The only way is to detect the zeros at the end, and that won't work if your list also has zeros at the end. C++ doesn't track the size of the initializer list anywhere.

Comment: If your instructor has not already explicitly told you not to use the standard library then you realllllllllllllllllllllly should use it!

Comment: is that not the same as declaring the namespace std in the header?

Comment: If you have `using namespace std;` that doesn't mean you're actually *using* anything. It means you're including what's in that namespace into the current one. tl;dr; You dont have to write `std::` anymore. (Don't get me wrong, I'm not advocating the use of `using namespace std;`, no pun intended)

Comment: Got it, so I'll just do array<double, MAX_SIZE> instead of std::array<double, MAX_SIZE>, right?

Comment: That is a bad thing, not a good one. Also, you really should use std::vector rather than an array.

Comment: The assignment specifically says to use an array. And this is all basic stuff, where we are told to declare the namespace like that

Comment: Could you post the exact assignment?

Comment: the relevant part is this: 
Your method must take in any array of double data (i.e. you may NOT assume any special precondition about the data in this array that makes the problem easier), its logical size, a low and high bound for the data in the array, and how many categories to use in the histogram. You must use (almost) parallel arrays for your frequency table. Use a named constant for the maximum number of categories in any histogram and use it to size your arrays statically. (Later, we'll learn how to do this dynamically)

Comment: The key is "Your method must take in ... its logical size". You're not required to figure this out, it's passed to you.

Comment: I figured it mean I had to figure it out programmaticly and pass it, but I guess that makes sense. These instructions aren't the clearest; I've had way better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend using the standard library for that:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/

But you can also do:

sizeof( givenDataPoints ) / sizeof( givenDataPoints[ 0 ] );

But you are going to get 20 because you told the compiler to allocate space for 20 elements.

You need to keep track of what is considered to be an empty element.

Here is a similar question: [Find the count of elements in array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067419/find-the-count-of-elements-in-array-in-c)

I hope it helps.