# C++ getting number of data in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a simple array here:

```
int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
```

How can I get the number of data inside the array? As the array was set to 10, but there is only 5 data inside.

My desired outcome should be something like this:

```
int icount = sizeof(someNumbers); // This is wrong, but I have no idea how..
cout << icount << endl;
```

I need icount to return 5 instead of 10. How can I do that?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int someNumbers[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int icount = sizeof(someNumbers) / sizeof(int);
```

Comment: This works and it looks simple, but I wonder if it is a good practice to not define the size of the array when creating it?

Comment: @Pokee please take a look of your question again.

Comment: @Pokee It is defined by the number of elements in the initialization list.  That initialization is equivalent to `int someNumbers[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};`

Comment: Mind explaining the -1s?

Comment: This does not answer OP's exact question. While OP has accepted it as a solution, keep in mind that you are posting for an entire community here, not just for the asker. Thefore, it is best if you answer the exact question, and then suggest a better alternative. Alternatives are only preferred if there is no direct solution to the question; here, there is one.

Comment: @Busy The question was `How can I do that?`. I provided a solution, the difference between his code and mine is self explanatory. Please note, at the time of writing this comment your solution still contains broken and misleading code.

Comment: Also, you should take the effort to explain your code.

Comment: And you should take the effort to not write answers that are broken. There really is nothing to explain here. Please see my other answers if you really think I'm not taking the effort.

Comment: And you should take the effort to run my code in the compiler; heads up, it works __just__ fine.

Comment: Does it, really? http://ideone.com/pOGoL2

Comment: Firstly, answer works for the array OP posted here. Secondly, I answer the question exactly instead of moving off on an irrelevant tangent and posting an answer that is different fom the question itself. The user was asking for a static array, and not a dynamic one. If he was open to more options, then he should have specified it in his question. Your answer does not serve the purpose of the community, like I said before. It only adds a dimension to the post.

Comment: There is NO solution that works for a static array of ints, assuming all values are allowed. Providing a solution that "works in this case" is a riddiculous thing to do, as it might cause more harm than good. Also clearly the OP was open to more options since he accepted my answer. About the community stuff - when I look for an answer, I want it short, easy and working for all possible valid inputs.

Comment: Exactly. Had you explained this in your answer, you would not got so many downvotes. Like I said, your answer is not just for the user, its for the community, the same one that got you so many downvotes. OP liked your answer because he was open to it, but other members did not like it since you deviated from the original question. Answer the question; if there is no answer, state so and then post your own alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a static array where the size is predefined, you would have to use a `for` loop to run through your array. See example here:

```
int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
int icount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (someNumbers[i])
        icount++;
}

cout << icount << endl;
```

A bit of background information. If one of the memory blocks assigned to this array is not set by the user, it will store an empty value. Therefore, if we do `if(isNumber[i])` then it will return true if `someNumber` at `i`is filled with a value, and it will return false if not filled with a value.

That is how the for-loop works in the code I posted. For every run of the loop, when the if statement is true, (if `someNumber[i]` has a value), then the counter is incremented.

EDIT: This solution works fine; for your array, it will output 5. It also works for any int array; just change the counter to run while it less than the static size you assign for the array.

EDIT 2: this solution works as long as there is no zero in your array, because a zero will falsify the if-condition. See more in this stackoverflow post: [Find the count of elements in array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067419/find-the-count-of-elements-in-array-in-c). To overcome this obstacle, it is recommended that you use std::vector, or use a counter variable and update the exact number of memory locations in the array that are filled in this variable manually.

Comment: this is not good answer

Comment: Why not @H.DJEMAI, may I ask?

Comment: what about this initial array: if you have  { 16, 2, 77, 0, 40, 12071 }

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @H.DJEMAI, just fixed that.

Comment: Also consider that arrays in C are NOT automatically filled with 0s for you. The content of the array can be literally anything before you assign some values yourself.

Comment: True, I missed that guys. Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: @Kelm: That's only true when the array is completely uninitialized.  There are several cases where automatic fill with zero does occur, and one applies here (more elements than initializers).  Another case is zero-initialization of objects with static lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(someNumbers) / sizeof(int); i++){
        if(someNumbers[i]){
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using `if(someNumber[i])` alone because this will return true as long as someNumber[i] is not undefined. Therefore, this works.

This is the output:

```
5
```

You can always make this a separate function like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int dataInArray(int someNumbers[], int size);

int main(){
  int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071, 2};
    int count = dataInArray(someNumbers, 10);
    cout << count << endl;
  return 0;
}

int dataInArray(int someNumbers[], int size){
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(someNumbers[i]){
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you consider this int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071,10,0,0,0,7};

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!, a simple edit on the if will do. Editing the answer...

Comment: This wont work. You are incrementing the counter when the array at the counter is empty. This returns how many empty spaces there are in the array, not how many filled ones.

Comment: Actually, I see what you mean. Undefined numbers in an array are set to be 0 to fill out. What do you recommend to solve this?

Comment: Please see my answer. It is simply changing the comparison operator from == to !=.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I understand what you mean, that is the way I had it (Without the `|| someNumbers[i]==0`) but as @AbhishekAryan mentioned, this approach won't work if the user sets the values of some of the items to 0. `if(someNumbers[i])` will return return `false` if `someNumbers` at `i` is equal to 0. Also, if the user does not set any value to the array initially, it will have trash value. This trash value can be a number, making the condition true even by if the user has no set values to the array.

Comment: Yes, but if you check for `someNumbers[i]` baing equal to zero, then it returns a value of all the members of the array. This is because some compilers set the undeclared values in an int array to zero.

Comment: Definitely my approach of solving that by using `|| someNumbers[i]==0` is wrong. I fixed my answer, however, I believe the answer depends too much on the compiler (My compiler does not set the values to 0, they are trash values)

Comment: Ah, I see. On the online compilers, it sets the value to zero, hence returning me the static size of the array always.

Comment: Also take in mind that if the programmer sets his `someNumbers` array to be `someNumbers[10]= { 0, 0, 0, 1 }` our approach will return 1, which is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for just is not possible, because according to the language rules, there is no difference at all between:

```
int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
```

and

```
int someNumbers[10] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Both of them definitely initialize all ten elements.

If you're interested in finding the first zero (whether it was typed by the programmer or implied by the language rules) then @ABusyProgrammer's answer will help.

If you need to count zeros which the programmer typed, then you have to let the compiler infer the array (or initializer_list, as mentioned in comments) length from the initializer as @Kelm's answer shows.

There's no way to both detect zeros typed by the programmer and also specify the array size.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
int someNumbers[] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
cout << sizeof(someNumbers)/sizeof(int) <<endl;
```

This is because `sizeof(someNumbers)` does not give you the count of the array but rather the total number of bytes it is taking. So divide it by `sizeof(int)` and it will give you the number of integers in the array.

Also, if you specify `[10]` while declaring the array then the count of the array will be 10, regardless of whether it is initialized with fewer values. The way shown above, with an empty `[]`, it will automatic set the count according to the number of elements specified.

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/FgXKBm)

Comment: Not what the question asked for. The array is of static size, this would still return `10` instead of what OP wants, `5`.

Comment: @Kelm Sorry for that. I have included that in the ideone link but not in the answer. Apologies.